# refresh URL link from Google maps using R

Tags: r, url, geocoding, geocode

there.

When using Google maps, we can have the following link:

`maps.google.com.br/?q=newyork`

Which will actually be redirected to:

`https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Nova+York,+NY,+EUA/@40.7056497,-73.9780035,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62`

That is a link that contains latitude and longitude of the place in It. What i need is to, by having the first "type" of link obtain the second. I tried some functions from package `urltools` and even some packages of text mining, like `tm` and `XML`, but as nothing worked so far, i have no code to show but:

```
 library(tm)
 library(XML)
 URL <- getURL("maps.google.com.br/?q=newyork")
```

As it might seem already, what I want to extract its lat and long from the googlemaps links. I have inspected the page and didnt found it in the HTML. This way, im infering that If there us a way to obtain lat and long is with this conversion of links.

In advance, i mean to do this for a very large dataset so i cant use the googlemaps API (neither i have money to pay for the exceeding requests).

This is my problem. Sorry of i misspelled or wrote anything wrong. Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: Try passing `followLocation = TRUE`to `getURL()`. This will allow the call to be redirected to the propper page that contains lat/long-data.

Comment: Hi @Majo. Thanks for answering. I understood what you said, but the page itself doesnt seem to contain the lat/long (at least i didnt found it), got it?

Comment: Check out the `cacheResponse` in `head(URL)`, can you find it? Checking with online tools the result should be something like -73.97800349999999,40.7056497 for NYC.

Comment: Found it. Thats exactly It. Thank you very much. Now i'll have some work with regex.

Comment: Glad to help! Remember to be nice to them :) I think they prefer if you use the API and it's pretty simple.

Comment: Yes, thank you. What happens is that rigth now i have a dataset with almost 50.000 lines and no money ):

Comment: And of course no time, as always.

Comment: What sort of precision do you really need? Have you considered some sort of clustering to reduce the number of calls needed? Just a thought :)

Comment: A priori, i had thought in the most precision possible. But this is good Idea also, which would ease my life a lot (thanks again)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to start geocoding I suggest using the `ggmap` package and the `geocode` function:

```
library(ggmap)
NY<-'New York, NY'
location<-geocode(NY)
print(location)

revgeocode(c(location$lon, location$lat))
```

ggmap has access to the google database and has several nice functions for plot geospatial data on a variety of different maps.

Comment: I like that solution best, too, but it has the constraints of the API.

Comment: @Majo there are other non-Google solutions, such as the (Data Science Tookit](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#street2coordinates) that doesn't have API restrictions, but currently only work in the UK and US